# Why doesn't AsQueryable<T> imply a filter on the _t discriminator

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Assuming a model of

```
[BsonDiscriminator(RootClass = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof (Dog), typeof (Cat))]
class Animal
{
    public ObjectId Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
class Dog : Animal { public int BarkVolume {get;set;} }
class Cat : Animal { public int PurrVolume {get;set;} }
```

I can do the following:

```
var collection = new MongoClient().GetServer().GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<Animal("Animals");
collection.Save( new Dog { Name="spot", BarkVolume=7 } );
collection.Save( new Cat { Name="kitty", PurrVolume=2 } );
```

However if I then try and query just for cats with

```
var cats = collection.AsQueryable<Cat>();
foreach(var c in cats)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} purrs at {1}", c.Name, c.PurrVolume);
}
```

I'll get an exception "Element BarkVolume does not match any field or property of class Cat".

Of course, if I change my query to:
`var cats = collection.AsQueryable<Cat>().Where(x=>x is Cat);`

Then no problem, however there then is a warning stating that x is Cat is always true.

Is there a particular reason why the driver doesn't inject a test on the discriminator _t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a design decision (which after working with for some time, I agree with). To specify the `_t` filter you can use the `OfType` extension method which is cleaner than `x => x is Cat`.

In the MongoDB C# driver there are typed and untyped options for almost everything. The typed options are only for comfort, they don't change the resulting queries. This is a good thing when you really care about the query performance and index utilization.

For example if you query using a property only the specific type has you don't need to add `OfType` (and the resulting `_t` filter) and if you do the query engine might use the `_t` index which you might not want it to do.